# FIFO implementation, deadlock

Tags: c, queue, deadlock, fifo

```
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MIN(x, y)         ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))

#define TASK_LENGHT pow(10, 5) /* 0.1s */
#define TASK_COUNT 100
#define THREADS_CAP 1

struct fifo {
    size_t out;
    size_t in;
    size_t size;
    size_t len;
    pthread_spinlock_t lock;
    char data[1];
};

struct fifo *
fifo_alloc(size_t size)
{
    struct fifo *fifo;

    fifo = malloc(offsetof(struct fifo, data) + size);
    fifo->out = fifo->in = 0;
    fifo->size = size;
    fifo->len = 0;
    pthread_spin_init(&fifo->lock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
    return fifo;
}

void
fifo_free(struct fifo *fifo)
{
    pthread_spin_destroy(&fifo->lock);
    free(fifo);
}

size_t
fifo_in(struct fifo *fifo, const void *data, size_t len)
{
    size_t total, remaining, l;

    pthread_spin_lock(&fifo->lock);
    total = remaining = MIN(len, fifo->size - fifo->len);
    while (remaining > 0) {
        l = MIN(remaining, fifo->size - fifo->in);
        memcpy(fifo->data + fifo->in, data, l);
        fifo->in = (fifo->in + l) % fifo->size;
        fifo->len += l;
        data = (char *)data + l;
        remaining -= l;
    }
    pthread_spin_unlock(&fifo->lock);
    return total;
}

size_t
fifo_out(struct fifo *fifo, void *data, size_t len)
{
    size_t total, remaining, out, l;

    pthread_spin_lock(&fifo->lock);
    total = remaining = MIN(len, fifo->len);
    while (remaining > 0) {
        l = MIN(remaining, fifo->size - fifo->out);
        memcpy(data, fifo->data + fifo->out, l);
        fifo->out = (fifo->out + l) % fifo->size;
        data = (char *)data + l;
        remaining -= l;
    }
    fifo->len -= total;
    pthread_spin_unlock(&fifo->lock);
    return total;
}

int
fifo_is_empty(struct fifo *fifo)
{
    int empty;

    pthread_spin_lock(&fifo->lock);
    empty = fifo->len == 0;
    pthread_spin_unlock(&fifo->lock);
    return empty;
}

void *
process_task(void *datap)
{
    struct fifo *tasks = datap;
    int data;

    while (1) {
        puts("it blocks there");
        if (!fifo_is_empty(tasks)) {
            puts("this code never execute");
            fifo_out(tasks, &data, sizeof(data));
            if (data == -1) pthread_exit(0);
            printf("%lu => %d\n", pthread_self(), data);
            usleep(TASK_LENGHT);
        }
        puts("this code never execute");
    }
}

int
main(void) {
    pthread_t threads[THREADS_CAP];
    struct fifo *tasks;
    int data;
    size_t i;

    tasks = fifo_alloc(128);
    for (i = 0; i < THREADS_CAP; i++)
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, process_task, &tasks);

    for (i = 0; i < TASK_COUNT; i++)
        fifo_in(tasks, &i, sizeof(i));

    for (i = 0; i < THREADS_CAP; i++) {
        data = -1;
        fifo_in(tasks, &data, sizeof(i));
    }

    puts("wait for threads to process all tasks");
    for (i = 0; i < THREADS_CAP; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    fifo_free(tasks);
}
```

I debugged my program and it turned out that it blocks at the `pthread_spin_lock` in `fifo_is_empty`. I was trying to recreate this problem with the minimum code needed like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define THREADS_CAP 10000

struct test {
    pthread_spinlock_t lock;
};

pthread_barrier_t barrier;
int counter = 0;


void *
foo(void *data) {
    struct test *test = data;

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    pthread_spin_lock(&test->lock);
    counter++;
    pthread_spin_unlock(&test->lock);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct test *test;
    pthread_t threads[THREADS_CAP];
    size_t i;

    test = malloc(sizeof(test));
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, THREADS_CAP);
    pthread_spin_init(&test->lock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
    for (i = 0; i < THREADS_CAP; i++)
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, foo, test);

    for (i = 0; i < THREADS_CAP; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    printf("%d\n", counter);

    pthread_spin_destroy(&test->lock);
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);
    return 0;
}
```

but i was not able to. I just works for some reason in contrast to my previous code.
Does anyone have an idea what is causing there problem and how to fix it?

Comment: `...  char data[1];`?!? Read this: [**Flexible array member**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)  It was only standardized a bit over two decades ago... ;-)

Comment: High-contention, moderately expensive critical sections are not a use case well suited to spin locks.  But I don't think that's directly related to your deadlock problem.

Comment: `l` is a particularly unfortunate choice of variable names.  Aside from conveying no meaning itself, it is easily confused with the constant `1`.  In some fonts, the two are practically indistinguishable.

Comment: This is a block rather than a deadlock. If you had a deadlock you would have two or more blocked threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem took me a while to sort out, but I arrived there through working on a minimal reproducible example.  I ultimately cut out everything related to managing the FIFO data, some unneeded functions, and all of the looping, but I found that the failure behavior did not manifest if I changed the definition of `struct fifo`.

Finally, I realized that the problem is here:

> ```
>     struct fifo *tasks;
> ```

// ...

> ```
>         pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, process_task, &tasks);
> ```

in conjunction with

> ```
> void *process_task(void *datap) {
>     struct fifo *tasks = datap;
> ```

Bottom line: you are passing the address of your `tasks` pointer, a pointer to a pointer, but then your thread function tries to interpret it as a single pointer.  Undefined behavior results.

The correction is to pass `tasks` itself to the thread, not `&tasks`:

```
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, process_task, tasks);
```

Your program has other problems, but that resolves the one you asked about.